# LM3915 questions about data sheet and operation

Tags: lm3915

I am connecting the [LM3915](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm3915.pdf) to a PNP transistor to drive LEDs. I have it working in bar graph mode using one LED per output directly (no transistor).

On page 7 of the datasheet, it looks like pins 1,10-18 should put out a "0" when in the ON state. Connecting the PNP directly does not work.
Measuring the output of the LM3915, I get about 4V, when OFF and 3V when ON. I'm measuring using both DVM and O-scope.
I don't know how to drive the PNP with this output.

**Qs:**

**1)** Is my test result correct? If yes, where does it say this on datasheet? I see saturation voltage at 0.4V under output drivers (page 3, TI datasheet)

**2)** Page 3, electrical characteristics. What does Divider Resistance mean? I know what a voltage divider is, just what does it mean to do with this chip?

**3)** The threshold chart makes no sense to me. My range is 1.2V, I think (also don't know how to set this), but the threshold V chart (page 4) shows a range up to 10V.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: If you refer to the datasheet you could at least provide a link.

Comment: And a schematic would be nice. How did you connect the 3915 to the PNP?

Comment: I added your schematic.  Notice that the base of PNP will be about 12-0.7, or 11.3 volts.  The datasheet recommends VLED ≤ V+, although it is an open-collector output, so it's not clear what badness happens when VLED > V+.

Answer (score 1):

In [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/17914/what-transistor-do-i-need-to-drive-many-leds-and-how-should-i-hook-it-up/17919#17919) I explain how to drive a chain of LEDs from an LM3915, using PNP transistors. Is this what you want?

[image]

The divider is an internal resistor chain which creates the reference voltages for all comparators. Each of these comparators drives one output.

Comment: I saw this. I'm confused because I'm measuring 3V when it's ON

Comment: @Tom - I really can't comment on that without seeing a schematic!

Comment: it's coming...waiting for upload...

Comment: I'm not allowed to post images since my rep isn't 10.

Comment: @Tom - give us a link to it, we'll add it in your question.

Comment: Post link in your question to diagram and we will load it.

Comment: This is the one that doesn't work and that I have the Questions about .. everything is powered on 12VDC http://www.flickr.com/photos/77352888@N06/7087829781/in/photostream

Comment: This is the circuit that is working on 5V with discrete LEDs http://www.flickr.com/photos/77352888@N06/6941769806/in/photostream

Comment: It's in Bar mode, pin 9 is connected to +V

Comment: And...it's working. Grounding problem. Still would like to know why I see only 3V as the low on PIN 1, 10-18.

Comment: @Tom - Post that last comment as an answer, and accept it. You won't get reputation for it, but at least others will know the problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

Tom, the LM3915 is a very efficient, effective, easy to use, simple log scale LED driver. 
Why do you want to add a bunch of PNP's with current limiting resitors and mess it up?
Choose any color LED's you want with any brightness and viewing angle you want.  Red/yellow tend are ~ 1.7V, Blue,green & white are ~ 3.2V diode drops so if using a 5V supply the open collector current source drivers will read 3.3V on red LEDs when on and then float up to 4V with just leakage current biasing the diode @ ~1.4V which is near the "knee" of the diode V-I curve.

I use > 10,000 mcd 30deg Red LED's @ 20mA so that would be 5 Cd @ 10mA, which is the recommended max for all outputs active to the chip. That should be blinding across the room. ;) Of course you can adjust the output currents with the Ref Current which is approx 10% of output.

Look at Page 7 schematic. of spec sheet.
THe long string of resistors is a ladder of log-weighted values to give the logarithmic curve with all the comparitors to activate each LED.

Although you only need at least 2 R's to make a "divider"
 ( read .. voltage ratio from resistance ratio)

The input is driven to all differential comparitors and the maximum input threshold is set by the voltage R-hi on pin 6, which can be adjust on pins 7 and 8 just like a 3 terminal regulator ( read LM317 specs if a newb.)

Take note about using caps in notes to reduce false triggers from switching noise.

Actually this cct is much like our brain's analog computer in threshold decisions.

Comment: I think he is trying to make it work with a commercial LED device that is intended to work from 12V. I don't know what else a "LED black box" could constitute.

Comment: Possibly the OPs ominous "LED black box" contains an array of LEDs with only one common cathode. This would prevent him from using the OC outputs directly.

Comment: OP's schematic is the best solution if the LEDs need more than 30mA.