# using LM3915 to switch relay or motor

Tags: motor, relay, sound, lm3915

I am trying to  switch either a 12v motor or a relay with the outputs of a LM3915.

I have found an answer on this site about using a pnp transistor on the outputs to switch multiple leds. the circuit - such as this one:

[What transistor do I need to drive many LEDs and how should I hook it up?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/17914/what-transistor-do-i-need-to-drive-many-leds-and-how-should-i-hook-it-up/17919#17919)

works for leds but doesnt seem to make a motor spin, the 12v motor or relay just makes a tone.

Is it possible to use this circuit to work with motors or relays?

Any pointers in the right direction much appreciated. Thanks

[image]

Comment: Depends more on the choice of transistor than the choice of driver.

Comment: What output current did you configure for LM3915? What is your R1 and R2? Prefer P-Mosfet here

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly

Rules of Thumb for Design

- BJT switches are optimized with about 10% of hFE max as a saturated switch
- coils will flyback back EMF voltage need some clamp protection V=LdI/dt. RC, R or R+Diode or Zener + diode.
- Small relays can use signal diodes rated for 10% of DC current to meet  SOA on datasheet  with lots of margin
- Measure Motor DC resistance DCR to define surge current. It will be 10x the  full load (rated) current at full speed and 100x the no-load current +/-20%

  - then choose a transistor that can handle this current with margin and not overheat.
  - then choose base current to be 10% of hFE max based on Ohm's Law with worst-case supply tolerances
  - check that PD in transistor does not exceed 50% of max power spec to achieve a 50'C temp rise on the case ( and more inside)
  - It is OK to slightly exceed uC current since VoH is not a logic "1" level.
  - Be sure your supply can handle the 10x surge, otherwise ramp up PWM at some frequency to limit current in x seconds.